# R6010 abort() has been called

Tags: c++

http://pastebin.com/g5dJAAYM#
Выходит вот такая ошибка в данном коде... Что это может быть?
Код сделан в Visual studio.

Comment: @Рамиль Ибраев, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, в каким именно месте она возникает, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

1. Определитесь, Вы пишите на Си или на С++. В коде дикая смесь. Код можно сократить на порядок, если писать на нормальных плюсах.
2. Не нужно, без глубокого понимания, смешивать сишный способ ввода/вывода (puts, scanf, getchar) и плюсовый (`std::cin`, `std::out`). Это в большинстве случаев приводит к странному выводу.
3. Строка `strcpy_s(t[i],(strlen(b) + 1),b);`. Я понимаю, что майкрософт понапридумывала своих функций, но старайтесь не использовать подобный новодел. Есть нормальная функция `strncpy`, которая имеет нужную функциональность.
4. Абсолютно не понятно, какие данные хочет программа и что именно она с ними будет делать. Нужно хотя бы один пример входных данных и желаемый результат.

А вот указанная ошибка возникает как раз из-за того, что где-то неаккуратно обращаетесь к памяти. Но где... это сложно восстановить, я пример скомпилировал, но абсолютно не понимаю, что туда вводить.